# Getting error when building RN

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload image to firebase storage with react native. I fail in very beginning. I am near the end of my game project and this is only part that is missing.

I have added

```
new ImagePickerPackage(),
new RNFetchBlobPackage()
```

and also

```
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;
```

to MainApplication.java

Every time I run react-native run-android then I get this message:

> C:\Users\Hai\Desktop\projectHQ2\HaalariQuiz\android\app\src\main\java\com\manager\MainApplication.java:7:
>   error: package com.imagepicker does not exist import
>   com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
>                         ^                         C:\Users\Hai\Desktop\projectHQ2\HaalariQuiz\android\app\src\main\java\com\manager\MainApplication.java:8:
>   error: package com.RNFetchBlob does not exist import
>   com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;
>                         ^                         C:\Users\Hai\Desktop\projectHQ2\HaalariQuiz\android\app\src\main\java\com\manager\MainApplication.java:30:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               new ImagePickerPackage(),
>                   ^                                 symbol: class ImagePickerPackage
>   C:\Users\Hai\Desktop\projectHQ2\HaalariQuiz\android\app\src\main\java\com\manager\MainApplication.java:31:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               new RNFetchBlobPackage()

I just cannot understand the error or what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides adding the dependencies to MainApplication.java, you also need to add to build.gradle and settings.gradle.
Follow https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Manually-Link-Package to link the package for android. 
Follow https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/develop/README.md#install for image picker